# Multiple keyboards popping up on iPhone alert dialog?

Tags: iphone

I am setting up an alert with a text field in it so players can enter their name for a high score.  The game is oriented in landscape mode, but when I call to show the alert, the alert pops up in portrait mode while two keyboards are displayed, one in landscape and one(that's the size of the landscape one) in portrait mode.  Here's the code I'm using to setup the alert dialog:

```
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] retain];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
[dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
[dialog setMessage:@" "];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[dialog addTextFieldWithValue:@"name" label:@""];
CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 100.0);
[dialog setTransform: moveUp];
[dialog show];
[dialog release];
```

How do I make the alert show in landscape orientation and prevent it from showing two keyboards?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of this? (just for fun!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may care, here's a working solution, which works properly in landscape mode:

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] retain];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
[dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
[dialog setMessage:@" "];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
[nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[dialog addSubview:nameField];
CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 100.0);
[dialog setTransform: moveUp];
[dialog show];
[dialog release];
[nameField release];
```

Make sure you've created UITextField * nameField; in your .h file, then you can get at the text the user typed in by doing:
inputText = [nameField text];

in the - (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex method.

Comment: I see you do dialog=[[[UIAlertView alloc] init] retain] and [dialog release]. Both alloc and retain should be matched with one release, so I think there's a leak (unless there's another release somewhere else in your program); the 'retain' seems unnecessary in any case since alloc does it too.

Comment: So should I ditch the retain and release or what would be an appropriate solution?  I think I'm missing something...

Comment: @user21293: alloc already does a retain, so you don't need to retain it again